# HTML: Frameset Open in New window or Tab

Tags: html, frameset

I have a problem using in FRAMESET.

**Scenario:**

I'm using frameset. I have 5 links in my menu, when I click the home page its okay but when I open it in new tab or new window the design is not included.

Is there a way to bundled the design either the user open it using the new window or new tab?

*Here's my code for frameset:*

```
<frameset rows="120,*,30" border ="0">
<frame name ="top" src="header.php">

</frame>

<frameset cols="200,*" border ="0">
<frame src="menu.php" name="menu">
<frame src="index.php" name="main" scrolling="yes">
</frame>
</frameset>

<frame name="bottom" src="footer.php">

</frameset>
```

*Here's my code for my menu:*

```
<body bgcolor = "#585858">
    <b>User Menu :</b>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" target="main">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="main.php" target="main">Playlist</a></li>
    <li><a href="view_weeks.php" target="main">View Weeks</a></li>
    <li><a href="view_network.php" target="main">Network</a></li>
    <li><a href="view_netbldg.php" target="main">Station & Building</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

I already tried the _top, _self, _parent, _blank but not one of them I'm looking at.

Advance thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's by design.

If you want to work around it and force the framesets to be present in new windows, only viable option that comes to my mind is to have a javascript check on top of every child page for the frameset, and if there are none, redirect back to frameset page.

```
var isFramesetAvailable = (window.top !== window.self);
if (!isFramesetAvailable) {
  window.location.href = 'your_frameset_page.html#target_page';
}
```

and then your frameset page would check for the #target_page url fragment, and if it exists, load that frame.

Comment: hi Thanks for helping me...Its working but its always displaying the home page.Example when I click the second href the playlist link it will proceed to the home page not in the playlist page..

Comment: @PrincessToledo like I explained, in addition to this, you need "frameset page [to] check for the #target_page url fragment, and if it exists, load that frame.". That's something that needs to be done in addition to this.